# React App deployed page looks different from localhost

Tags: reactjs, deployment, create-react-app, github-pages

After working locally on my computer, I tried publishing my website for the first time using `npm run deploy`. When I go to the url, all the components are there but for some reason, they're larger in dimensions than what I saw on localhost.

Here's what it looks like locally: 
[image]

Here's what it looks like on the deployed website: 
[image]

Could someone explain what's going on here?

Comment: Check the network tab in the debugging tools, maybe its failing to load a stylesheet of font or something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like your localhost is zoomed out (and not the remote website). So it might explain why it looks a bit different on your localhost. Try reseting the zoom in Chrome it might solve your problem.

[image]

Comment: Yes, that was it!
I can't believe it hahaha!